# Cannot create shiny white bands animation as shown in material view

Tags: animation, shaders, shader-nodes, emission

I'm making some wormhole animation where I added white shiny bands to it with *Emission* using a *Wave Texture*, but the render output doesn't display as in the following Material Preview:

[image]

I'm mixing a Glass shader to it so I can get this nice wobbly refractive effect.

[image]

This is the output I get and the bands are only slightly visible. You will see it when you change color, i.e. red. I like the final output as is, I just want the white emission bands to be included.

[image]

You can see the bands only slightly as dark black rings. I need them to add this to add some fast moving effect illusion.

[image]

Why does the output look different from the preview and how do I fix this? And also I tried different settings I can't get it to adjust distance between each wave band. The scale will also increase the width of the band, but I want it to stay relatively thin.

[image]

Comment: You set PrincipledBSDF > Alpha to 0.001 :) Also if you want to affect Emission by blue ColorRamp you should connect it into Emission (not Color) socket.

Comment: yes i set it low coz alpha 1 also didnt work, it makes the band way too thick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a colorramp so that the band isn't that big? alpha is 1 in my example

[image]

Comment: hey chris thank you! exactly what i figured out too :D

Comment: you are welcome